# plot.xts + abline not quite accurate?

Tags: r, xts

I am using `xtsExtra` to plot some scatter graphs of xts objects and wanted to draw a horizontal line through zero but it looks like its in the wrong place...please see the code below? is this a bug?

```
set.seed(123)
require(xts)
f <- xts(rnorm(100,0.0001,0.003),Sys.Date()-c(100:1))
f1 <- xts(rnorm(100,0.0001,0.003),Sys.Date()-c(100:1))
require(xtsExtra)
plot(f,f1)
abline(h=0,col='red')
```

Comment: maybe, but why would you use xts objects like that?  plot.xts expects the x-axis to be timeBased.

Comment: ok...even if you did `plot(f)` to get an x-asis time base then `abline(h=0, col='red')`, it's still wrong...

Comment: I share GSee's views. Vote to close as unconstructive unless questioner can come up with a meaningful reason for in effect using an object called "eXtensible Time Series" *without* a time series.

Comment: When I try `plot(f); abline(h=0)` the line appears in the correct location, so exactly what is "wrong"? It's also not clear whether you are trying to do a scatterplot of the coredata values or want a "parallel-plot" of two time indexed series.

Comment: @SlowLearner How is this unconstructive? One draws an `xts` plot and then wants to `abline` on it. For example I `quantmod::getSymbols('GDP',src='FRED')` and want to shade recessions....it's a common use case.

Answer (score 3):

Jeff Ryan may have answered this [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/plotting-vertical-lines-on-months-in-xyplot-tp2992254p3380734.html):

Try,

```
abline(v=.index(X)[50], col="red")
```

Note the "dot" in `.index`.  The fact is that `xts` uses the internal
`POSIXct(like)` time for the x-axis, so you need to access it that way.

Comment: Thanks for that comment, but it doesn't solve the horizontal line case...as the `v` is for vertical...also in my example, the x-axis is not time...

Comment: @h.l.m ok. Using `quantmod::getSymbols('GDP',src='FRED')` I had no problem with `abline(h=0)`, only with the `v`.

Comment: @h.l.m With your example I was able to `abline(h=.5)` and get a line in the middle.

Comment: I think that the values that `v` and `h` used are based on a new scale...that is used by `plot.xts`, just not too sure how to access and efficiently use that scale so that it is intuitive...

Comment: This is great! I ended up with the following code: abline(v=index(my.xts.data)[endpoints(my.xts.data, "days")]). In this way R makes grid lines for daily time steps.