# How to plot simple vertical line with abline() in R?

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I'm unable to add a vertical, or horizontal line to my graph. I feel I'm missing something very simple, but I can't seem to find it. I've copied some examples from the internet but it won't work. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I'm trying:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("^FTSE", src="yahoo", from=as.Date('2004-01-01'), 
           to=as.Date('2013-01-01'), periodicity="weekly")

plot(FTSE$FTSE.Close)
abline(v='2008-01-01', col="red")
```

I've also tried:

`abline(h = 5000, col="red")`
and
`abline(h = mean(FTSE$FTSE.Close), col="red")`

But they also won't work. No lines are shown.

I just want a vertical line. I'm using RStudio.

Comment: Try `abline(v=1, col="red")`, where lies the line on the x-axis?

Comment: Doesn't work how?

Comment: This is what I get with `abline(v=1, col="red")`: https://imgur.com/d1poYSI

Comment: Please always state all `library` calls, this time I've helped you.

Comment: Duplicate, interesting but not answered: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18923382/6574038

Comment: I think it's something peculiar of the dataset. abline() always works, except with this plot.

Comment: It's still weird, look at my answer, and `all.equal(class(FTSE), class(sample.xts))` yields `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, we will have to use `xts::addEventLines`.

There was actually an [issue opened at github](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/47) on Feb, 2015 that `abline` simply won't work with the new `plot.xts` and we should use the alternative.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("^FTSE", src="yahoo", from=as.Date('2004-01-01'), 
           to=as.Date('2013-01-01'), periodicity="weekly")

plot(FTSE$FTSE.Close)
# abline(v='2008-01-01', col="red")  # won't work

# alternative
events <- xts("", as.Date("2008-01-01"))
addEventLines(events, col="red", lwd=2)
```

#### Result

[image]

*Note:* It's also possible to define multiple event lines, e.g. `events <- xts(letters[1:3], as.Date(c("2008-01-01", "2009-01-01", "2010-01-01")))`
.

Comment: I wonder why it was so hard to find this information online. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>This probably should be issued at CRAN.</strike> *(This was already issued at [github](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/47), solution is posted in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56881627/6574038).)*

Here's a workaround.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51488119/6574038) answer, we could plot a vertical constant rather with `lines` than with `abline`. `plot.xts`, which is used when we plot a `"xtx"` object, seems to be somewhat buggy or messy written as it also a comment signalizes in the linked answer, and which suggests to use `zoo::plot.zoo` instead.

From [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25022112/6574038) answer we learn, that we may use `.index()` to extract the indices that are below the data, similar to factors where the values lie below the labels.

However, `plot.zoo` prunes the dates according to an unknown smoothing algorithm (which probably can be figured out by looking deeply into `zoo::plot.zoo`), and our date we're plotting could hit precisely such a "black hole". One possible solution is to give `plot.zoo` a `sapply` broadside of x-coordinates. I've written a function `genXcords`

```
genXcords <- function(data, date, tadj=0, ladj=0) {
  idx <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(.index(data), origin="1970-01-01"))
  se <- seq(as.Date(date) - 5 - tadj, by="day", length.out=21 + ladj)
  y.crds <- .index(data)[which(min(se) < idx & idx < max(se))]
  return(y.crds)
}
```

that first pulls out the dates from the numerical indices. Next, it creates a sequence of dates containing the date to be plotted somewhere within. Note the adjustment parameters `tadj` and `ladj`, because will will need some fine-tuning afterwards. (Probably the function itself has to be further refined!) Eventually, the function throws a battery of x-coordinates which we can try to plot.

Now let's test `genXcords` method on an example.

```
# load package
library(xts)

# get data
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix)

# create line data
y.cords <- genXcords(sample.xts, "2007-05-16", -6, -18)  # note the adjustment!

# plot 
zoo::plot.zoo(sample.xts[,"Close"])
invisible(sapply(y.cords, function(x) lines(x=rep(x, 100), 
                                  y=seq(0, max(sample.xts$Close) + 10, length.out=100), 
                                  col="red", lty=2, lwd=2)))
```

I manually adjusted the `tadj` and `ladj` parameters until just one single vertical line appeared at the right place. This resulted in the plot below.

[image]

***Note:*** Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work with the `FTSE` data. But in principle, as one can see it works, and instead of deleting my code I put it here.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting issue. Here is my workaround. I took the row index and made them into a column, then I translated the plot into `ggplot` so that I could have a little more control on the plot. Let me know if anything in the code is ambiguous.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("^FTSE", src="yahoo", from=as.Date('2004-01-01'), 
           to=as.Date('2013-01-01'), periodicity="weekly")

FTSE %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column("date") %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date,FTSE.Close ))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date('2008-01-01'), col="red")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(6), 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~., breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(6)))+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d %Y", date_breaks = "2 years")+
  ggtitle("FTSE.Close",subtitle = "2014-01-01/2012-12-27")+
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `v` argument (for **vertical**) not the `h` argument (for horizontal). Here's a reproducible example:

```
d <- data.frame("y" = 1:5, 
                "dates" = paste0("2012-01-0", 1:5))

plot(d$y ~ d$dates)

abline(v = which(d$dates == "2012-01-01"), col = "red")
```

Comment: This does work, but I can't reproduce this with my example.