# abline() in zoo plot puts lines in wrong location

Tags: r, plot, xts, zoo, abline

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875191/how-to-plot-simple-vertical-line-with-abline-in-r) that `abline()` does not work with `xts` plots. I typically use `plot(as.zoo())` of `xts` objects and ran into the following problem. Let's first generate some dummy time series data (the definition of `start` and `end` turn out to be crucial):

```
library(xts)
start <- strptime("1888-01-01 00:30", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC")
end   <- strptime("2019-12-31 00:10", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC")
n <- 1000
dates <- seq(start, end, length.out = n)
set.seed(1)
dat <- rnorm(n)
ts <- xts(dat, order.by = dates)
```

Now let's try to plot `ts` as a `zoo` object and add lines:

```
plot(as.zoo(ts), type = "p")
abline(v = as.Date("1950-01-01"), col = "red") # not placed at the right location
abline(v = as.Date("2000-01-01"), col = "blue") # same (wrong) placement
abline(v = strptime("1950-01-01 00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC"), col = "green") # also fails
```

All `abline()` calls seem to plot in the same (wrong) location, why?

Remark: The following uses a different definition of `start` and `end` and that works as expected:

```
start. <- as.Date(start)
end. <- as.Date(end)
dates. <- seq(start., end., length.out = n)
ts. <- xts(dat, order.by = dates.)
plot(as.zoo(ts.), type = "p")
abline(v = as.Date("1950-01-01"), col = "red")
```

Comment: look at `axis(3)`, and you're mixing date with date-time objects `plot(as.zoo(ts), type = "p"); abline(v = as.numeric(strptime("1950-01-01 00:30", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC")))` and `as.numeric(as.Date("1950-01-01"))` is approximately 0 on the scale of the x-axis

Comment: ... nice, thanks. Any chance to get `abline()` to draw at a given date-time object?

Comment: yes you just have to use `abline(v = as.numeric(...))` as in my example for some reason, i thought this would be automatic/coerced to numeric for you, but apparently not

Comment: Ah, I see, indeed, `abline(v = as.numeric(strptime("1950-01-01 00:30", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC")))` works, thanks. Do you want to formulate this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. `abline` doesn't know what class you originally used on the X axis when the plot was created.  It just takes the internal numeric value of whatever you give it.  If you plot it using one class and use a different class in `abline` it is not going to work.
2. In plotting and most other cases it is better to use POSIXct class rather than POSIXlt class.  That is do NOT use `strptime` as it produces POSIXlt.  Use `as.POSIXct` as it produces POSIXct.  The internal form of a POSIXlt object is a list of 9 components which `abline` can't interpret in the desired way.
3. Regarding the subject of the post this has nothing to do with zoo. `abline` works this way even without any packages.  If you had used `plot(dat ~ dates)` then the `abline` command would have resulted in the same output.

Thus the code should be

```
library(xts)

fmt <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
start <- as.POSIXct("1888-01-01 00:30", format = fmt, tz = "UTC")
end   <- as.POSIXct("2019-12-31 00:10", format = fmt, tz = "UTC")
n <- 1000
dates <- seq(start, end, length.out = n)
set.seed(1)
dat <- rnorm(n)
ts <- xts(dat, order.by = dates)

plot(as.zoo(ts), type = "p")
v <- as.POSIXct("1950-01-01 00:00", format = fmt, tz = "UTC")
abline(v = v, col = "green")
```

[image: screenshot]